# Logic for strings with saperated commas with different values in two textviews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have one key with string with comma separated values. i.e. "template_id": "9,10" / "template_id": "0".  From API I'm getting 10 different parameters for each ids.

```
 template_id=0 => Blank
 template_id=1 => Out of Stock
 template_id=2 => Birthday
 template_id=3 => Gold Exclusive
 template_id=4 => Selling Fast
 template_id=5 => Almost out of Stock
 template_id=6 => Use Parameter name "Points"
 template_id=7 => Use Parameter name "Price"
 template_id=8 => Use Parameter name "Venue"
 template_id=9 => Use Parameter name "No of Locations"
```

**I am using `Recyclerview`**. I have added below code for checking ids and add textview settext according the ids:

```
if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("10")) {

            holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setText(model.getStart_to_end());
        }

        if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("9")) {


            holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setText(model.getNo_of_locations() + " Locations");
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setText(model.getStart_to_end());
        }

        if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("8")) {

            holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setText(model.getVenue());
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setText(model.getStart_to_end());
        }

        if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("7")) {

            holder.mBinding.ivPrice.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_reward_dollar);
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setText(model.getPrice());
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_selected));
            holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("6")) {


            holder.mBinding.ivPrice.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_reward_point);
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setText(model.getPoints());
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_selected));
            holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("5")) {

            holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setText(R.string.almost_out_of_stock);
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setText(model.getStart_to_end());
            holder.mBinding.ivMembership.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_selling_fast);
            holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_selected));
            holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("4")) {


            holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setText(R.string.selling_fast);
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setText(model.getStart_to_end());
            holder.mBinding.ivMembership.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_selling_fast);
            holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_selected));

            holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("3")) {

            holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setText(R.string.gold_exclusive);
            holder.mBinding.ivMembership.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_gold_exclusive);
            holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGold));

            holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("2")) {

            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setText(mCMSTextData.getBirthday());
            holder.mBinding.ivPrice.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_birthday);

            holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("1")) {

            holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setText(R.string.out_of_stock);
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setText(model.getStart_to_end());
            holder.mBinding.ivMembership.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_out_of_stock);
            holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

            holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("0")) {

            holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.mBinding.llPrice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

But every time this textview got override by other values. I have tried by taking 20 `TextView` and conditions but still not working.

**============ EDIT ==============**

Adapter Class :

```
public class CatalogueAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CatalogueAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    private List<CatalogueData> dataList;
    private Activity activity;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    private OnRecyclerItemClickListener mListener;
    private CMSTextData mCMSTextData = new CMSTextData();
    private CustomSharedPreference prefManager;

    public CatalogueAdapter(Context context, List<CatalogueData> dataList, OnRecyclerItemClickListener mListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = dataList;
        this.mListener = mListener;
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.color.colorTextHint)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_mall_logo)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_mall_logo)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();

        prefManager = PrefManager.getInstance(context).getPrefs();
        mCMSTextData = new Gson().fromJson(prefManager.getString(PARAMS.KEY_CMS_TEXT, ""), CMSTextData.class);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RowCatalogueBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                , R.layout.row_catalogue, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (dataList.size() > 0) {

            final CatalogueData model = dataList.get(position);
            holder.mBinding.setCurrentData(model);

            imageLoader.displayImage(model.getImage4x3(), holder.mBinding.ivCatalogue, defaultOptions);
            imageLoader.displayImage(model.getLevel_logo_image(), holder.mBinding.ivLogo, defaultOptions);


             /* template_id=0 => Blank
                  template_id=1 => Out of Stock
                  template_id=2 => Birthday
                  template_id = 3 =>Gold Exclusive
                  template_id = 4 =>Selling Fast
                  template_id = 5 =>Almost out of Stock
                  template_id = 6 =>Points
                  template_id = 7 =>Price
                  template_id = 8 =>Venue(Event hall A, AMK Hub)
                  template_id = 9 =>No of Locations(3 Locations) */

            String n1[] = new String[1000], n2[] = new String[1000];
            String template_id = model.getTemplate_id();
//
//            for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
//
//                n1[i] = template_id.split(",")[i];
//                Log.d("values", n1[i]);
//            }
////
//            n1[position] = template_id.split(",")[0];
//            n2[position] = template_id.split(",")[1];
//
//            Log.d("values", n1[position]);

            List<String> items = Arrays.asList(template_id.split("\\s*,\\s*"));

            Log.d("items", items.get(0));

            if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("10")) {

                holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setText(model.getStart_to_end());
            }

            if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("9")) {

                holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setText(model.getNo_of_locations() + " Locations");
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setText(model.getStart_to_end());
            }

            if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("8")) {

                holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setText(model.getVenue());
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setText(model.getStart_to_end());
            }

            if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("7")) {

                holder.mBinding.ivPrice.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_reward_dollar);
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setText(model.getPrice());
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_selected));
                holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("6")) {

                holder.mBinding.ivPrice.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_reward_point);
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setText(model.getPoints());
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_selected));
                holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("5")) {

                holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setText(R.string.almost_out_of_stock);
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setText(model.getStart_to_end());
                holder.mBinding.ivMembership.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_selling_fast);
                holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_selected));
                holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("4")) {

                holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setText(R.string.selling_fast);
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setText(model.getStart_to_end());
                holder.mBinding.ivMembership.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_selling_fast);
                holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_selected));

                holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("3")) {

                holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setText(R.string.gold_exclusive);
                holder.mBinding.ivMembership.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_gold_exclusive);
                holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGold));

                holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("2")) {

                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setText(mCMSTextData.getBirthday());
                holder.mBinding.ivPrice.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_birthday);

                holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("1")) {

                holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setText(R.string.out_of_stock);
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setText(model.getStart_to_end());
                holder.mBinding.ivMembership.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_out_of_stock);
                holder.mBinding.tvMembership.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

                holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            if (model.getTemplate_id().contains("0")) {


                holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.mBinding.llPrice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
//
//            if (model.getCatalogue_type().equals("2") || model.getCatalogue_type().equals("3")) {
//
//                holder.mBinding.llMembership.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                holder.mBinding.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//
//                holder.mBinding.ivPrice.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_clock_black);
//                holder.mBinding.ivMembership.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_location_catalogue);
//
//            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }


    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final RowCatalogueBinding mBinding;

        ViewHolder(RowCatalogueBinding itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView.getRoot());
            this.mBinding = itemLayoutView;
            mBinding.llMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.onViewClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }


}
```

Model :

```
public class CatalogueData
{
    private String catalogue_type;
    private String unique_code;
    private String name;
    private String short_description;
    private String long_description;
    private String terms_conditions;
    private String image4x3;
    private String image16x9;
    private String created_date;
    private String is_mercatus_group;
    private String is_featured;
    private String reward_type;
    private String start_date;
    private String end_date;
    private List<String> periods = null;
    private String points;
    private String price;
    private String no_of_locations;
    private List<String> address = null;
    private String selling_lable;
    private String mall_id;
    private List<Object> schedule = null;
    private String template_id;
    private String venue;
    private String level_logo_image;
    private String start_to_end;
    private String is_birthday;
    private String gold_exclusive;
    private String price_value;
    private String points_value;
}
```

Please suggest anything. Let me know if you require any code.

Comment: post your adapter class and model object, would be helpful.

Comment: @Sajith i have edited the question. please check

Comment: @Annie : you are using one  same textview to set the text for all values?

Comment: @UzairAslam Yes but i also tried using 20 textviews. let me edit the code.

Comment: @Annie what you want? Do you want to display all value at same time or only one value ?

Comment: @UzairAslam it reaches the limit so i can't upload code. but if you have any suggestions then please

Comment: @NiranjPatel All values in different rows. like first row will have may be9,10 then it will have both textview second row have 3 then it will have one textview and so on

Comment: All of your if conditions are true.

Comment: @Sajith Yes can be as this is recycler view so every item has own conditions

Comment: @Annie keep all TextView separate then store all template_id in ArrayList with split then use condition, I'm sure it will work.

Comment: Can you please post an answer

Comment: @Annie check my answer. It very simple logic there.

Comment: @Annie issue solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep all `TextView` separate then save all template_id in `ArrayList` with split then use condition, I'm sure it will work. Please check below code snippet.

```
    String template_id = model.getTemplate_id();
    ArrayList<String> templateIDs = new ArrayList<>();
    StringTokenizer templateTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(template_id, ",");
    while(templateTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        templateIDs.add(templateTokenizer.nextToken());
    }

    if(templateIDs.contains("0")) {
        // Do your work according 0 value
    }

    if(templateIDs.contains("1")) {
        // Do your work according 1 value
    }

    if(templateIDs.contains("2")) {
        // Do your work according 2 value
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
.equals("YOUR_ID_HERE")
```

instead of

```
.contains("YOUR_ID_HERE")
```

and see if that helps

Comment: This should be comment instead of answer.

Comment: @NiranjPatel I  do not have enough reputation to comment everywhere pal

Comment: @Annie You could check for 9,10 for that case `also you could convert your if statements into a switch case`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're splitting the template_id but then calling contains on the full un-split string.

If you received template_id("10,6") then the if statements would be called for 10, 6, 1 and 0.

Only guessing as I don't know the context but I imagine you actually want to use the split values and check each value individually. Also I would imagine you want to use an if-else-if ladder rather than sequential if statements.

Answer (score 1):

Loop the **items**  arraylist instead,

```
Iterator i = items.iterator();

  while (i.hasNext()) {
     if(items[i].equals("9"){
          //write your logic here
     }
     if(items[i].equals("10"){
          //write your logic here
     }
     if(items[i].equals("1"){
          //write your logic here
     }
     //and so on write your every condition

  }
```